# Nautilus "Connect to Server" is much slower than the terminal's SSH

Tags: 18.04, ssh, nautilus, remote, aws

In both machines I usually operate on, one at home and another at work, Nautilus seens to work pretty fast when it comes to my local files. However, as soon as I connect it using the SSH option on Nautilus, it becomes really painfully slow, taking 2-5 seconds to open a folder, while a terminal ssh session would take just a fraction of a second to run a `cd` command. 
The same goes for copying files, with a `cp` being nearly instantaneous on terminal-SSH, while 
it takes a lot more in Nautilus.

The worse case, however, happens when i try to copy any of my local files to the remote side using Nautilus: it may take several minutes, maybe an hour, if the file (a tar, for example) is too big (500MB or bigger, let's say) while a `sftp > put` or `scp` would last seconds, or just a few minutes at worse.

Isn't Nautilus supposed to run the same SSH/SFTP connections and commands? If yes, why would it be considerably slower than the terminal on that?

Update: both of my machines were attempting to connect to the same server, which happens to be an AWS ec2 instance. Those two can use the nautilus remote session with no significant delay between them, only the AWS machine offers this kind of issue on both. While this may seen an AWS issue, I still don't see how can the SSH terminal be way faster than Nautilus even on AWS.

Update 2 : The same problem happens on `pcmanfm`, so this may be not a Nautilus problem after all.

Comment: for the sftp issue, do you have an entry in `~/.ssh/config` for that server? Im thinking maybe the auth stage needs to fail a number of times before trying something else

Comment: Yes, I do. I normally will use the Host name declared in the config for connecting via terminal. Using only the host name or the full ssh string still makes no difference to Nautilus performance.

Comment: how about starting nautilus from the command line just to see more debug information when trying to connect? `G_MESSAGES_DEBUG="all" NAUTILUS_DEBUG="Window" nautilus` (that will output a lot of info, even from dependencies if Im not mistaken)

Comment: Nothing special seems to be notified, even while connecting to the server or copy files to/from it. Here's the pastebin with the result: https://pastebin.com/dgrN2yrz

Comment: Well, I never got a solution, really. Just coming back to say that VSCode has an amazing extension called Remote:SSH which is way faster than nautilus, so that worked for me, but I won't post is as a solution since the problem with nautilus is still a thing.